# CLion for PHP Extension development?

Tags: ide, php-extension

I'm developing a PHP extension. I choose to use CLion since I'm familiar with IntelliJ, but it seems CLion doesn't support Makefile which is generated by `phpize`. Is there any workaround to make CLion recognize phpize macros?

Or can anyone recommend a IDE supporting PHP extension development better?

Answer (score 0):

We can't use cmake to build, but we can configure CMakeList.txt for the php extension to work in CLion;

Use `execute_process` to get the proper include directories from `php-config`.

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND php-config --include-dir
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE PHP_SOURCE
)

string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" PHP_SOURCE "${PHP_SOURCE}")

message("Using source directory: ${PHP_SOURCE}")

include_directories(${PHP_SOURCE})
include_directories(${PHP_SOURCE}/main)
include_directories(${PHP_SOURCE}/Zend)
include_directories(${PHP_SOURCE}/TSRM)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Add a custom target for `configure`

```
add_custom_target(configure
    COMMAND phpize && ./configure
    DEPENDS ${SOURCE_FILES}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Add a dummy library with the source files

```
add_library(___ EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

---

Check out the following article for the full setup for building and debugging PHP extension in CLion.

https://dev.to/jasny/developing-a-php-extension-in-clion-3oo1

Answer (score 0):

CLion 2020.2 shipped with Makefile support. From my experience it works alright, but not as good as projects that have direct CMake support. At least not yet!